# "I thought about how this machine works/worked." (confusion about past vs. present)

Tags: tenses, past-tense, present-tense, sequence-of-tenses

I'm not certain about which tense to use in this sentence: *"I thought about how this machine _____."* (This is coming from a scenario where I had previously used the machine and started to think about its inner-mechanisms.)

Would I use **"worked"**, since my thought occurred in the past, or **"works"**, since I am assuming the machine still works to the present day?

Comment: ..how this machine *would work*.

Comment: I should have been more specific, my bad. This is coming from a scenario where I had previously used the machine, and started to think about its inner-mechanisms.

Comment: If it is still working, I would say that 'works' is the most suitable. It is an attribute of the machine and is neither past nor present. It just is. (Until it stops working.)

Answer (score -1):

I would use "*worked*".

"I'm thinking about how this machine *works*" would be the *present* form. 
"I thought about how this machine *worked*" if the above happened in the past.

I would not use "*would work*", because it's a translation in the past of something like:
"I'm thinking about how this machine *will work*".

If I'm wrong, then apologies!